# How to create an error that is captured in angular promise

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I am trying to understand how to get to the reject part of the .then() in angular.

**C# Method**

```
public int Foo(){
 int foo = 1;
 return foo;
}
```

I have tried throw `HttpResponseException` with `404` and `500`, however even that response is caught and handled in the first part of the .then() promise. I just want to understand what sort of error needs to occur for it to go into the latter part.

I have used this as source to throw the response exception

[Throw HttpResponseException or return Request.CreateErrorResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519561/throw-httpresponseexception-or-return-request-createerrorresponse)

Example angular method

```
foo.then(function(response){
  //success do something
}), function(error){
   // how to come here?
})
```

If I haven't explained well please do let me know, I am simply after getting to the `reject` part of the function.

Comment: Hey Harry, a 404 or 500 response is seen as a successful call. Because you asked and you received information. The error phase is triggered when the http call isn't successful. E.a. a timeout. You could test this by setting a very short timeout on the call, or just make a call to a wrong path or server.

Comment: Do you have any HTTP response interceptor?

Comment: @stevenca oh i see that makes sense thanks

Comment: @dotctor no I do not have them

Comment: Well, not sure if it's just a transcription error, but you have an end parenthesis before your error function... Also, you can look at using the `.catch()` handler instead of the overload on `.then()`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry if there errors are there, it is just for demonstration. if i implement .catch() you are suggesting this will capture the error? but what kind of error do i need to generate?

Comment: I would do some research into how to handle exceptions in promises. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/36345046/215552 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/26534303/215552

Comment: sure you had the right answer b4 yer man posted the example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286629/toggle-checkbox-using-javascript   thought you deserved an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `int` from your C# method, you should return `IHttpActionResult`.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Foo()
{
    try 
    {
        int foo = 1;
        return Ok(foo);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        // log exception or whatever you need to do
        return InternalServerError(exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but wouldnt this still be caught in the success part of the .then()

Comment: The `Ok()` response will trigger your success callback, but the `InternalServerError()` response will trigger the error callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up with one of your brackets. The error handler for a promise must be included INSIDE the ".then" method.

replace this:

```
foo.then(function(response){
  //success do something
}), function(error){
   // how to come here?
})
```

with

```
foo.then(function(response){
  //success do something
}, function(error){
   // how to come here?
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks but the code is for demo purpose and this does not answer my question.